# Symfony 2 + GELF

Tags: symfony, monolog, graylog2

I'm trying to set up Symfony 2 with GELF to be used with GrayLog. I am on Symfony 2.0.17 and using the information from this GIST https://gist.github.com/2654837 I have set the logging to DEBUG mode and am not receiving and information in Graylog.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Seems Symfony 2.1 has GELF built in that seems to be working.